# Can I use CHIRP for programming a Baofeng DM-5R?

Tags: baofeng, radio-programming

I can't find my Baofeng DM-5R in the CHIRP list of supported radios. I've been told that I should try by telling CHIRP to assume a different radio from the DM-5R - perhaps the UV-5R!? Do you know if this is a feasible option? I am able to manually program the DM-5R, but it's too onerous. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Baofeng Tech download page](https://baofengtech.com/download) says:

> At this time our DMR radios are not compatible with CHIRP; you will need to use the OEM software to update and program your BTECH DMR radios.

Here's a [CHIRP "issue"](https://chirp.danplanet.com/issues/4507) (actually a feature request), which is open and not complete, to add support for the DM-5R.  It seems clear, unfortunately, that CHIRP doesn't yet support the DM-5R.  However, the Baofeng Tech download page does offer OEM software to program the radio.  I'd suggest trying that as an alternative.